# How to setup a Jasmine / Chutzpah unit tests project running TypeScript files?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

I have tried setting up a unit-tests project to cover front-end code in TypeScript with Jasmine and Chutzpah, but have a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

I have created a sample ASP.NET projet in which I have extracted and included the [default jasmine tests](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html). Pressing F5 opens a browser and makes the tests pass.

I have then converted all the tests to TypeScript and included [its definitely typed definitions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jasmine.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/). Pressing F5 opens a browser and makes the tests pass.

[image]

I have finally installed Chutzpah with its Visual Studio extension, but I'm not able to either make the tests pass using the Visual Studio/Resharper Unit Tests window or the default chutzpah console. At this stage, pressing F5 still opens a browser and makes the tests pass.

[image]

That's the last step I'm struggling with. For clarity of the discussion, I have setup [a sample projet on GitHub](https://github.com/springcomp/TypeScript.Jasmine.Chutzpah.Sample) to reproduce my problem. I'm sure it must be something really simple but I just cannnot figure it out.

The project can be found at the following location:
https://github.com/springcomp/TypeScript.Jasmine.Chutzpah.Sample

Comment: Do you have a chutzpah.json configuration file telling Chutzpah how to run your tests?

Comment: Yes, I have. That's probably what I'm struggling with the most. Would you please take a look at the repro project at the GitHub location referred to in the question? Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the 'Why', I'm still trying to get my head round this myself.  However it might get you a bit further forward..

I saw the same behavior when I pulled down your project.  If I put the below reference paths in at the top of the PlayerSpec.ts :

```
///<reference path="../src/Player.ts"/>
///<reference path="../src/Song.ts"/>
///<reference path="../spec/SpecHelper.ts"/>
///<reference path="../Scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
```

After this Resharper runs the tests successfully with them passing.

I can't explain why - maybe resharper doesn't use the SpecRunner file for picking up references?